# How to write query that will do unusual distinct select from sql table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Suppose I have some table in SQL Database with **many** data and some of the rows are almost identical, for example:

```
|===========================================|
|           Message                         |
|===========================================|
|              ...                          |
|-------------------------------------------|
|    account is rejected: <aa>              |
|-------------------------------------------|
|    account is rejected: <bb>              |
|-------------------------------------------|
|    mailbox unavailable: 550 550 <1@b.com> |
|-------------------------------------------|
|    mailbox unavailable: 550 550 <2@b.com> |
|-------------------------------------------|
|                 ...                       |
```

for my purposes 2 first lines are identical and 2 last lines are identical, so the query should return

1. account is rejected:
2. mailbox unavailable: 550 550

I thought to write query that will select rows, eliminate chars after '<' sign and the will do `DISTINCT`, but I don't know how to do all it in `SELECT`

Can you help me to write such query?

Comment: Will every message have a `<` in it?  And will you always want to ignore everything from the *first* `<` onwards?

Comment: @Dems, not every message have a `<`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following removes everything from the first `<` onwards.

The `GROUP BY` is more flexible than using `DISTINCT` but accomplishes the same thing in this case.

The `CASE` statement is there to cater for the possibility of messages that do not have a `<` in them.  If there is *always* a `<` Then just use the `ELSE` section instead.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<', Message) = 0 THEN Message ELSE LEFT(Message, CHARINDEX('<', Message)-1)) END AS Message
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<', Message) = 0 THEN Message ELSE LEFT(Message, CHARINDEX('<', Message)-1)) END
```

Comment: @Dems, can I use regex in select/case?

Comment: @theateist - Not on TSQL unless you wrote your own.  But you don't need to, CHARINDEX() does what you need...

Comment: @theateist - yes.  Look at the CHARINDEX() function.  Find all text before the first `<` and all text after the subsequent `>`, then concatenate those two results.